# Google Sheets data validation different for each row

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For my current project, I'm making a sheet that lets me keep track of my D&D characters. I use data validation to remind me what all the options are for various stats, with the information being kept in a separate "RefTables" sheet. Creating a data validation for selecting a character class is very easy, since there are only 14 classes total. What I'm having trouble with is the 'subclass' column. After you choose the character class, you get to choose your specialization, or 'subclass'. This differs depending on the character class you chose.

Right now I can do the proper data validation for each cell individually. In my ref tables sheet, I have a section where it will grab the character class value and put all the 'subclass' options into a row. I can then use data validation in that specific cell to grab the subclass row. This works, but is tedious to do for every single cell.

The formula I would love to put in the range section is

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("RefTables!Q",ROW(),":AJ",ROW()))
```

which appends the row number with the appropriate columns so each row automatically gets its own subclass row (EX: RefTables!Q3:AJ3, RefTables!Q21:AJ21, etc.). I've seen solutions for Excel, but I'm using Google Sheets so I can share this document more easily with friends.

tldr; How to use data validation in Google Sheets that is slightly different for each row

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this is possible to achieve only the manual way setting it up for every single cell/row. Google Sheets' Data validation does not support injecting CSVs via formula.